# how can I make 6 RisedButton in row and column | flutter & dart

Tags: flutter, dart

**Flutter & dart**

I want to make my app look like this:
**[app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTm7d.png)**

but currently my buttons is under each other by the column, I couldn't manage them with the row and column widget and with the text above them as well.

so is someone please know how can I make the buttons like that and write a text above the button?

**my code:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
            body: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 20,
                  ),
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(height: 30),
                      Container(
                        child: RaisedButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                          child: Ink(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                gradient: LinearGradient(
                                  colors: [
                                    Color.fromRGBO(34, 46, 62, 1),
                                    Color.fromRGBO(34, 46, 62, 1),
                                    // Color.fromRGBO(75, 83, 228, 1),
                                    // Color.fromRGBO(113, 90, 206, 1)
                                  ],
                                  begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                  end: Alignment.centerRight,
                                ),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
                            child: Container(
                              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                                  maxWidth: 183.0, minHeight: 70.0),
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              child: Text(
                                "English",
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 17,
                                    fontFamily: 'Montserrat-Arabic',
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 30),
                      Container(
                        child: RaisedButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                          child: Ink(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                gradient: LinearGradient(
                                  colors: [
                                    Color.fromRGBO(34, 46, 62, 1),
                                    Color.fromRGBO(34, 46, 62, 1),
                                    // Color.fromRGBO(75, 83, 228, 1),
                                    // Color.fromRGBO(113, 90, 206, 1)
                                  ],
                                  begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                  end: Alignment.centerRight,
                                ),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
                            child: Container(
                              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                                  maxWidth: 183.0, minHeight: 70.0),
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              child: Text(
                                "English",
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 17,
                                    fontFamily: 'Montserrat-Arabic',
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 30),
                      Container(
                        child: RaisedButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                          child: Ink(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                gradient: LinearGradient(
                                  colors: [
                                    Color.fromRGBO(34, 46, 62, 1),
                                    Color.fromRGBO(34, 46, 62, 1),
                                    // Color.fromRGBO(75, 83, 228, 1),
                                    // Color.fromRGBO(113, 90, 206, 1)
                                  ],
                                  begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                  end: Alignment.centerRight,
                                ),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
                            child: Container(
                              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                                  maxWidth: 183.0, minHeight: 70.0),
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              child: Text(
                                "English",
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 17,
                                    fontFamily: 'Montserrat-Arabic',
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 30),
                      Container(
                        child: RaisedButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                          child: Ink(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                gradient: LinearGradient(
                                  colors: [
                                    Color.fromRGBO(34, 46, 62, 1),
                                    Color.fromRGBO(34, 46, 62, 1),
                                    // Color.fromRGBO(75, 83, 228, 1),
                                    // Color.fromRGBO(113, 90, 206, 1)
                                  ],
                                  begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                  end: Alignment.centerRight,
                                ),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
                            child: Container(
                              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                                  maxWidth: 183.0, minHeight: 70.0),
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              child: Text(
                                "English",
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 17,
                                    fontFamily: 'Montserrat-Arabic',
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 30),
                      Container(
                        child: RaisedButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                          child: Ink(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                gradient: LinearGradient(
                                  colors: [
                                    Color.fromRGBO(34, 46, 62, 1),
                                    Color.fromRGBO(34, 46, 62, 1),
                                    // Color.fromRGBO(75, 83, 228, 1),
                                    // Color.fromRGBO(113, 90, 206, 1)
                                  ],
                                  begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                  end: Alignment.centerRight,
                                ),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
                            child: Container(
                              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                                  maxWidth: 183.0, minHeight: 70.0),
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              child: Text(
                                "English",
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 17,
                                    fontFamily: 'Montserrat-Arabic',
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 30),
                      Container(
                        child: RaisedButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                          child: Ink(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                gradient: LinearGradient(
                                  colors: [
                                    Color.fromRGBO(34, 46, 62, 1),
                                    Color.fromRGBO(34, 46, 62, 1),
                                    // Color.fromRGBO(75, 83, 228, 1),
                                    // Color.fromRGBO(113, 90, 206, 1)
                                  ],
                                  begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                  end: Alignment.centerRight,
                                ),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
                            child: Container(
                              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                                  maxWidth: 183.0, minHeight: 70.0),
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              child: Text(
                                "English",
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 17,
                                    fontFamily: 'Montserrat-Arabic',
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 20,
                  ),
                ])));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the Answers Above also good practice but for me as I, use nullsafety on flutter I, simpley usually do is create a separate widget and call them on e.g.

```
    class YourWidgetwithTopText extends StatelessWidget{

           final String? textonTop;
           final Function()? function1;
           final Function()? function2;
           final String? buttonName1;
           final String? buttonName2;
           final double? height;
           final double? width;
    
     const YourWidgetwithTopText({this.textonTop,this.function1,this.function2,this.buttonName,this.buttonName2,this.heigth,this.width});

      @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Container(
        child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
        children: [
           Text(textonTop!),
              
           SizedBox(height: 10),
            
           Container(
          child: Row(
            children:[
            
              GestureDetector(
              onTap: function1,
                 child: Container(
                    height: height!,
                    width: width!,
                     decoration: BoxDecoration( 
                        color: Colors.accent
                       borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),
                  child: Center(
                      child: Text(buttonName1!) 
                     )
                 )
                 ),
        
                SizedBox(width:10),
              
                 GestureDetector(
              onTap: function2,
                 child: Container(
                    height: height!,
                    width: width!,
                     decoration: BoxDecoration( 
                        color: Colors.accent
                       borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),
                  child: Center(
                      child: Text(buttonName2!) 
                     )
                 )
                 ),
            ]
         )
      ),
         ]
        )
     );
    }
```

}

then after creating a separate widget which hold some information.

```
class Test extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
         body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInset.only(
              left: 20 , right: 20),
               child: Column(
               children: [
              //Then call widget its should be like this.

                YourWidgetwithTopText(
                   textonTop: "Text on Top 1"
                   function1 : (){},
                   function2: (){},
                   buttonName1:"Button 1",
                   buttonName2: "Button 2",
                   height: 60,
                   width:  110
                ),
               //Put some SizeBox for spacing above or below
                YourWidgetwithTopText(
                   textonTop: "Text on Top 2"
                   function1 : (){},
                   function2: (){},
                   buttonName1:"Button 1",
                   buttonName2: "Button 2",
                   height: 60,
                   width:  110
                ),
               YourWidgetwithTopText(
                   textonTop: "Text on Top 3"
                   function1 : (){},
                   function2: (){},
                   buttonName1:"Button 1",
                   buttonName2: "Button 2",
                   height: 60,
                   width:  110
                ),
  
              ]
              )  
            ),
          )   
      ),
     );
     }
}
```

for starter you can try do this.

Comment: how would it be with riasedbutton?

Comment: you can change the Container to RaisedButton or wrap it with container  with height and width then the result still same and also Remove the GestureDetector . But i Implore you to start at flutter 2 since its have nullsafety

Comment: Thanks a lot! it worked for me, can I have any of your contact info? I would like to ask you another thing

Comment: Sure, Friend a.chil6663@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GridView` from [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html).

Like this example you can paste on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?null_safety=true&id):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(Test());
}

class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
        body: GridView.count(
          primary: false,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
          crossAxisSpacing: 10,
          mainAxisSpacing: 10,
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: const Text("He'd have you all unravel at the"),
              color: Colors.teal[100],
            ),
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: const Text('Heed not the rabble'),
              color: Colors.teal[200],
            ),
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: const Text('Sound of screams but the'),
              color: Colors.teal[300],
            ),
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: const Text('Who scream'),
              color: Colors.teal[400],
            ),
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: const Text('Revolution is coming...'),
              color: Colors.teal[500],
            ),
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: const Text('Revolution, they...'),
              color: Colors.teal[600],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: how can I change the container or the card size?

Comment: using the height and width property

Answer (score 0):

As per the reference given, I think you should code in this format:

```
Column(
 children: [
   Text(),
   Row(
     children: [
       RaisedButton(),
       RaisedButton(),
     ]  
   ),
   SizedBox(),

   Text(),
   Row(
    children: [
     RaisedButton(),
     RaisedButton(),
    ]  
   ),
   SizedBox(),

   Text(),
   Row(
    children: [
      RaisedButton(),
      RaisedButton(),
    ]  
   ),
 

 ],
),
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: _App(),
    ),
  );
}

class RowWithButtonsData {
  final String text;
  final String leftButtonText;
  final String rightButtonText;
  final VoidCallback leftButtonPressed;
  final VoidCallback rightButtonPressed;

  RowWithButtonsData({
    required this.text,
    required this.leftButtonText,
    required this.rightButtonText,
    required this.leftButtonPressed,
    required this.rightButtonPressed,
  });
}

final rowsList = [
  RowWithButtonsData(
      text: 'Row1',
      leftButtonText: 'Row1 Left Button',
      rightButtonText: 'Row1 Right Button',
      leftButtonPressed: () {},
      rightButtonPressed: () {}),
  RowWithButtonsData(
      text: 'Row2',
      leftButtonText: 'Row2 Left Button',
      rightButtonText: 'Row2 Right Button',
      leftButtonPressed: () {},
      rightButtonPressed: () {}),
  RowWithButtonsData(
      text: 'Row3',
      leftButtonText: 'Row3 Left Button',
      rightButtonText: 'Row3 Right Button',
      leftButtonPressed: () {},
      rightButtonPressed: () {}),
];

class _App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: rowsList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, i) => RowWithButtons(
            text: rowsList[i].text,
            leftButtonText: rowsList[i].leftButtonText,
            rightButtonText: rowsList[i].rightButtonText,
            leftButtonPressed: rowsList[i].leftButtonPressed,
            rightButtonPressed: rowsList[i].rightButtonPressed,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class RowWithButtons extends StatelessWidget {
  const RowWithButtons({
    Key? key,
    required this.text,
    required this.leftButtonText,
    required this.rightButtonText,
    required this.leftButtonPressed,
    required this.rightButtonPressed,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String text;
  final String leftButtonText;
  final String rightButtonText;
  final VoidCallback leftButtonPressed;
  final VoidCallback rightButtonPressed;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text(text),
          SizedBox(
            height: 5,
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: leftButtonPressed,
                child: Text(leftButtonText),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 10,
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: rightButtonPressed,
                child: Text(rightButtonText),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

With data class you need just to add new item in `rowsList` to add new row, so it's more scalable and elegant solution imho.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You are not using a new row widget when you enter a new row.
Every time you start a new row use a Row() widget.

First of all you should create a Widget for the raised button.

```
Widget Button_Raised(){
onPressed(){}, child: Text('Your text goes here'),}
```

Like this.
And don't use those Containers everywhere you can wrap the widget above inside container.
And finally wrap your Column around a Wrap widget this will cause the row to automatically shift to the next line when filled.

Use a new row everytime you start a new row.

Comment: You also, should pass the text to the Widget otherwise all the bottons will have the same text, like:  Widget Button_Raised(String myText){
onPressed(){}, child: Text(myText),}